# How to resolve this error:- http://Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_

Tags: c#, telerik

Whenever I perform any action on my page then this error occurs.

http://Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=ctl01_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3a4ae4914f-8c8e-4123-9d05-414d87b48357%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%2c+Version%3d2014.1.403.40%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d121fae78165ba3d4%3aen-US%3aca584452-327f-4858-bf00-fb22c6f6fd75%3a16e4e7cd%3af7645509%3a24ee1bba%3af46195d3%3a2003d0b8%3a88144a7a%3a1e771326%3aaa288e2d%3ab092aa46%3aed16cbdc%3a874f8ea2%3a92fe8ea0%3a19620875%3afa31b949%3a490a9d4e%3abd8f85e4%3a4cacbc31%3a78b9daca%3ab7778d6c%3a7c926187%3a8674cba1%3ac08e9f8a%3aa51ee93e%3a59462f1%3a2e42e72a%3aef347303:15

This happens only on my machine in mozilla browser. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you using AJAX update panels?

Comment: yes using update panels

Comment: If you remove your update panels, does it run successfully?  This is always the first thing I try when I get one of these errors.

Comment: hi Seano666, but using update panel project running on another system as well as on server,it gives only error on my machine in mozilla browser and in chrome working fine

Answer (score 0):

This is not an awful lot to go on.  I do recall receiving an error message similar to this though and in order to solve it, added the following into the `web.config`:

```
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
```

Let me know what the outcome is.

Comment: hi,i have implemented this.but still giving error:-
Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.